# How is kernel oom score calculated?

Tags: oom

Looked on The Google, and couldn't find anything that explained how the score in `proc/<pid>/oom_score` is calculated. Why use this score instead of just using the total memory used?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See Goldwyn Rodrigues's [2009 article](https://lwn.net/Articles/317814/) for the implementation at that time, Jonathan Corbet's [2010 article](https://lwn.net/Articles/391222/) for what I believe is the current behavior, and Jonathan Corbet's [2013 article](https://lwn.net/Articles/548180/) for ideas about future changes.

From the 2010 article:

> In David's patch set, the old badness() heuristics are almost entirely
>   gone. Instead, the calculation turns into a simple question of what
>   percentage of the available memory is being used by the process. If
>   the system as a whole is short of memory, then "available memory" is
>   the sum of all RAM and swap space available to the system. If,
>   instead, the OOM situation is caused by exhausting the memory allowed
>   to a given cpuset/control group, then "available memory" is the total
>   amount allocated to that control group. A similar calculation is made
>   if limits imposed by a memory policy have been exceeded. In each case,
>   the memory use of the process is deemed to be the sum of its resident
>   set (the number of RAM pages it is using) and its swap usage.
>
> This calculation produces a percent-times-ten number as a result; a
>   process which is using every byte of the memory available to it will
>   have a score of 1000, while a process using no memory at all will get
>   a score of zero. There are very few heuristic tweaks to this score,
>   but the code does still subtract a small amount (30) from the score of
>   root-owned processes on the notion that they are slightly more
>   valuable than user-owned processes.
>
> One other tweak which is applied is to add the value stored in each
>   process's oom_score_adj variable, which can be adjusted via /proc.
>   This knob allows the adjustment of each process's attractiveness to
>   the OOM killer in user space; setting it to -1000 will disable OOM
>   kills entirely, while setting to +1000 is the equivalent of painting a
>   large target on the associated process.

Comment: Is it possible for all processes to have a 0 oom score? Currently booting off a live cd results in this.